# how to get ruamel yaml emit blank instead of null?

Tags: yaml, ruamel.yaml

Using ruamel.yaml, the emitted yaml is created like so:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

ydata = dict(
  apiVersion='compliance.openshift.io/v1alpha1',
  disableRules=None,
  extends='tbd',
  kind='TailoredProfile',
  metadata=dict(name='Best Practices NIST CONTROLS Profile'),
  setValues=dict(v1='tbd'),
  title='tbd',
)

yaml = YAML(typ='safe')
yaml.default_flow_style = False      
with open(output_filepath, 'w') as outfile:
    yaml.dump(ydata, outfile)
```

and looks like this:

```
apiVersion: compliance.openshift.io/v1alpha1
disableRules: null
extends: tbd
kind: TailoredProfile
metadata:
  name: Best Practices NIST CONTROLS Profile
setValues:
  v1: tbd
title: tbd
```

But I want **null** to be blank, like so:

```
disableRules:
```

How can that be done?

Comment: What's `ydata`? Please give a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @user2133121 You should tag questions about ruamel.yaml with the tag [tag:ruamel.yaml] that way people who are subscribed to that tag get notified.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `typ='safe', which dumps faster then the default, but does always dump` None` as null. If you use the (default) roundtrip dumper, you'll get
the empty null representation when possible:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

data = dict(
  apiVersion='compliance.openshift.io/v1alpha1',
  disableRules=None,
  extends='tbd',
  kind='TailoredProfile',
  metadata=dict(name='Best Practices NIST CONTROLS Profile'),
  setValues=dict(v1='tbd'),
  title='tbd',
)

    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
apiVersion: compliance.openshift.io/v1alpha1
disableRules:
extends: tbd
kind: TailoredProfile
metadata:
  name: Best Practices NIST CONTROLS Profile
setValues:
  v1: tbd
title: tbd
```